# Aligning divs to the top

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a really basic layout with two divs. The idea is to have one div to the left and the other to the right in the same line. However they don't have the same height.

Why is the smaller div aligned to the bottom instead of to the top? Is not that the expected behavior within the page flow?

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="left debug-green"></div>
        <div class="right debug-red"></div>
    </div>
</body>


body {
    font-size: 0;
}
.left {
    width: 50%;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.right {
    width: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.debug-red {
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
.debug-green {
    background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
}
```

This is a js fiddle sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/3nAsx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most browsers render `inline-block` element with default `vertical-alignment` value and that value is: `baseline`

`vertical-align` values:

```
    vertical-align: baseline     /* keyword values */
    vertical-align: sub
    vertical-align: super
    vertical-align: text-top
    vertical-align: text-bottom
    vertical-align: middle
    vertical-align: top
    vertical-align: bottom
    vertical-align: 10em          /* <length> values */
    vertical-align: 4px
    vertical-align: 20%           /* <percentage> values */
    vertical-align: inherit
```

Answer (score 4):

add to the right div

```
vertical-align: top;
```

Comment: but, what's the reason behind the div align to the bottom? is the css specification in someplace defining that value?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the `display:inline-block;` declarations with `float:left;`. Since you're specifying the dimensions anyway, you don't need `inline-block` property. Here's how it looks like after I made the change.

[image]

**Code**

```
.left {
    width: 50%;
    height: 30px;
    float:left;
}
.right {
    width: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    float:left;

}
```

Comment: thanks, but what's the reason for the div to be bottom aligned?

Comment: Good question, not sure, but probably a default.

Answer (score 0):

vertical-align: top;

Is good option.

But if you just want one div on left and other on right.

Give float: left to left div and float : right to right div

Answer (score 0):

This way is good short coding

```
  <div class="wrap">
     <div class="left debug-green"></div>
     <div class="right debug-red"></div>
  </div>

   .wrap div{
     width: 50%;
     height: 30px;
     display: inline-block;
     background-color: green;
     float:left;
     vertical-align:top;
   }

 .right {
     height: 20px !important;
     background-color:red !important;
  }
```